# How do I cancel a bid on an auction?

Tags: diablo-iii

This morning I encounted a rare occurance with the Diablo 3 auction house.

I had a bid on an item where I was winning with a few hours left to go.

During the course of my game playing I found an item that was better than what I was wearing AND better than the item that I had a bid on. I went to the auction house interface and could not find a way to cancel the winning bid I had on the item. Luckily for me, someone else bid and won the item before the auction ended so I recovered my gold.

The question is, am I able to/can I cancel my bid an item?

Comment: I don't think you can in real life either :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot cancel your bid. The best you can hope for is to be outbid, or to be able to resell the item for more than you paid for it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cancel your bid once it is placed. That is the risk with bidding on an item well before the auction is over. If you find something better, you're still stuck unless someone outbids you. This is why you can expect bids to come in much closer to the end of an auction than the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer **No** you can't

This is a safety mode for the seller.

If you bid on something, you may avoid others bids. So if you canceled your bid, no one was gonna get the item.

It's work as a Real Auction house. If you bit on something, you must pay for it.